# How to compile litecoin osx mavericks

Tags: c++, terminal, macports, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am trying to make a demo cryptocurrency based on litecoin but before even starting to do this, I am currently unable to compile litecoin (unaltered) source code into litecoind.

First I installed the dependencies using Macports:

```
sudo port install boost db48 qt4-mac openssl miniupnpc git
```

Cloned from github. (https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git)
In terminal navigated to the src folder and ran:

```
make -f makefile.osx USE_UPNP=-
```

It starts compiling and then gives me the following error:

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [litecoind] Error 1

I have xcode and have a bit of programming knowledge, but please try and explain in simple terms how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to compile source that uses 32-bit specific system calls as 64-bit application?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. I copied the source from github (I don't know if it's designed to be 32bit or 64bit) for my 64bit (I believe) 10.9.1 macbook pro.

Comment: `ld` is a linker. It seems, it cannot find 64-bit variant of some dependencies. Try reading their docs. They talk about rebuilding dependencies on MacOS `x64` here https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/commit/ed725643cad5bc71dc8cbc73d6121b2d6e644634#diff-5c9db1d4619895b002078a3529a8dc72L130

Comment: I don't think you linked to the right thing. Thanks anyway, but I can't find anything about 64-bit dependencies, it just seems to be a list of changes from bitcoin to litecoin.

Comment: Sorry, found it! Thanks.

Comment: _"Some ports also seem to obey either `build_arch` or
  `macosx_deployment_target`, but not both at the same time. For example, building
 +on an OS X 10.6 64-bit machine fails. Official release builds of Litecoin-Qt are compiled on an OS X 10.6 32-bit machine to workaround that problem."_